# Calculate Numeric Value inside a String within a Pandas Column

Tags: python, string, pandas, count

I have a pandas dataframe and I can select a column I want to look at with:

```
column_x = str(data_frame[4])
```

If I print column_x, I get:

```
0     AF1000g=0.09
1     AF1000g=0.00
2     AF1000g=0.14
3     AF1000g=0.02
4     AF1000g=0.02
5     AF1000g=0.00
6     AF1000g=0.54
7     AF1000g=0.01
8     AF1000g=0.00
9     AF1000g=0.04
10    AF1000g=0.00
11    AF1000g=0.03
12    AF1000g=0.00
13    AF1000g=0.02
14    AF1000g=0.00
...
```

I want to count how many rows that contain the values AF1000g=0.05 or less there are. As well as rows that contain the values AF1000g=0.06 or greater.

```
Less_than_0.05 = count number of rows with AF1000g=0.05 and less

Greater_than_0.05 = count number of rows with AF1000g=0.06 and greater
```

How can I count these values from this column when the value in the column is a String that contains string and numeric content?

Thank you.

Rodrigo

Comment: It would be a good idea to have the column called AF1000g and make the values the only thing in the column. This should be your problem and then all the other stuff will come easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) to extract the numerical values, and do the counting there:

```
vals = column_x.apply(lambda x: float(x.split('=')[1]))
print sum(vals <= 0.05) #number of rows with AF1000g=0.05 and less
print sum(vals >= 0.06) #number of rows with AF1000g=0.06 and greater
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment above makes a good point. Generally you should focus on parsing before analyzing.

That said, this isn't too hard. Use [pd.Series.str.extract](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.extract.html) with a regex, then force to a float, then do operations on that.

```
 floats = column_x.str.extract("^AF1000g=(.*)$").astype(float)
 num_less = (vals <= 0.05).sum()
 num_greater = (vals > 0.05).sum()
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the boolean array returned by the comparison with `vals` can be forced to 0s and 1s.